# why moving Elements using appendChild wont work on JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to move some pictures on Mobile view and remove them from the previous Places.
I've tried this code, but it ends up with this error: TypeError: picPos is null ?
whenever I console log the pic or picPos, the log looks exactly the way it should be.
can any one understand why?

```js
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  for(var i = 0; i<=3; i++){
    let picPos = document.getElementById("container"+(i+1));
    let pic = document.getElementById("box"+(i+1));
    picPos.appendChild(pic);
  }
  
  })
```

```css
#container2>div{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
<div id="container3"></div>

<div id="container2">
  <div id="box1">1</div>
  <div id="box2">2</div>
  <div id="box3">3</div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Whenever I console log it, the log shows everything the way it should be.

Comment: For container, you are using class in the div but using getElementByID

Comment: Don't add a comment to explain your question. Add the information to the question itself

Comment: also, your loop continuation condition should be `i < 3`, not `i <= 3`. Even when you fix your HTML to use IDs, this will look for an element with ID `container4`, which you don't have

Comment: @JuanMendes I reverted your edit as it seemed to try to change the fundamental question here.

Comment: @Dominik Sorry, I was playing with it and did not mean to save it

Comment: All good @JuanMendes. This question is not exactly straight forward :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use id attributes in your HTML if you're using `getElementById`.

I've also changed your loop to start at `1` so you don't have to add 1 each time in your loop. It depends on the rest of your app if that's a good idea or not.

As I'm not sure what's supposed to happen in your code I leave that up to you.

```js
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  for(var i = 1; i<=3; i++){
    let picPos = document.getElementById("container"+i);
    let pic = document.getElementById("box"+i);
    picPos.appendChild(pic);
  }
})
```

```css
#container4>div{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" class="container1"></div>
<div id="container2" class="container2"></div>
<div id="container3" class="container3"></div>

<div id="container4">
  <div id="box1">1</div>
  <div id="box2">2</div>
  <div id="box3">3</div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Your example has two elements with the ID `container2`

Comment: Also, what's supposed to happen when you click the button?

Comment: I see one red box going into one of the divs but it should be all three of them?

Comment: Ohh, they are all being moved, it's just the CSS that's not fixed

Comment: the problem was somehow with the (i+1) and now it's solved, thank you :)